# How can I avoid the "an import path cannot end with .ts extension" error in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, deno

I'm using Visual Studio Code to write Deno programs.

The import statement in Deno contains the `.ts` extension, e.g.

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
```

which is marked as a problem in VS-Code, error code ts(2691):

[image]

Despite the shown error, the program works fine, but I want to avoid the error message, because there's nothing wrong.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This can be solved by installing and configuring the [Deno Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=denoland.vscode-deno) for VSCode.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to open the extensions view,
then type "deno" and click on the entry name "Deno - Deno support for VSCode":

[image]

and install it.

After installation, you can choose any one of following methods:

- Go to settings: (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> or　<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> on MacOSX), select "**Extensions>Deno**" and click on the checkbox under "**Deno:Enable**" and "**Deno:lint**"

  - Just enable **workspace settings** only
  - **Don't enable User settings** if you have other **Non node projects**

[image]
[image]

- Or, as @hong4rc mentioned, open the Command Palette(<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>) and select `Deno:initialize`

Either method creates a folder named `.vscode` and a file `settings.json` with the following lines in your workspace project ( **workspace settings**):

```
{
  "deno.enable": true,
  "deno.lint": true
}
```

In both cases, after restarting Visual Studio Code, the error should be gone.

Comment: You can run `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type deno init (it auto enable another setting, just remove if you want)

Comment: @hong4rc thanks, so you can switch on nd off the extension with a command.I tried but got an error message "Init failed, Source: Deno (Extension)". Any idea why?

Comment: Try this: disable `tslint`(if you installed), reopen VScode, check your project in the normal disk (!= C)

Comment: Wow! Works just as expected!

Comment: this does not resolve it for me.

Comment: As @hong4rc mentioned, Ctrl+Shift+P and type `deno: initialize workspace`  resolved for me.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by disabling `typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics` in the workspace.

Answer (score 7):

*Since this is the first question that pops up in search I will add my answer here although it was not related to Deno, but with Webdriver.*

Adding `allowImportingTsExtensions` in tsconfig.json solved the issue.

My full answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76332913/1778834