# How do I create a telegram bot ? Error by implementing modul from deno in first line?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, deno

```
import { TelegramBot, UpdateType } from "https://deno.land/x/telegram_chatbot/mod.ts";   <--- ERROR 
import "https://deno.land/x/dot_env@0.2.0/load.ts"

const TOKEN = ("MYTOKENID");
if (!TOKEN) throw new Error("Bot token is not provided");
const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN);

bot.on(UpdateType.Message, async (message: any) => {

    const text = message.message.text || "I can't hear you";

    await bot.sendMessage({ chat_id: message.message.chat.id, text: `echo ${text}` })

});

bot.run({
    polling: true,
});
```

[{
"resource": "/Users/bgrnaymane/Documents/GitHub/crypto_price_api/telegrambot.ts",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "2691",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Ein Importpfad darf nicht mit einer Erweiterung ".ts" enden. Importieren Sie ggf. stattdessen "https://deno.land/x/telegram_chatbot/mod".",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 2,
"startColumn": 41,
"endLineNumber": 2,
"endColumn": 86
}]

Ein Importpfad darf nicht mit einer Erweiterung ".ts" enden. Importieren Sie ggf. stattdessen "https://deno.land/x/telegram_chatbot/mod".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid the "an import path cannot end with .ts extension" error in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65115527/how-can-i-avoid-the-an-import-path-cannot-end-with-ts-extension-error-in-vsco)

Comment: this code example may be helpful 
https://github.innominds.com/michael-spengler/telegram_chatbot/blob/master/examples/04-webhook-oak.ts

Answer (score 4):

#### A better alternative

I don't know much about the library you are using currently but there is a much better option availaible for making telegram bots and it's written in deno and typescript, but it supports deno and node both due to transpiling.
The library is called [grammy](https://grammy.dev/) also it has a ton of plugins and a wonderful team of devs working to improve it.

A code snippet from the official docs to show how cleaner the code is in grammy.

```
import { Bot } from "https://deno.land/x/grammy/mod.ts";

// Create an instance of the `Bot` class and pass your authentication token to it.
const bot = new Bot(""); // <-- put your authentication token between the ""

// You can now register listeners on your bot object `bot`.
// grammY will call the listeners when users send messages to your bot.

// Handle the /start command.
bot.command("start", (ctx) => ctx.reply("Welcome! Up and running."));
// Handle other messages.
bot.on("message", (ctx) => ctx.reply("Got another message!"));

// Now that you specified how to handle messages, you can start your bot.
// This will connect to the Telegram servers and wait for messages.

// Start the bot.
bot.start();
```

you can give it a try if you want ...also the link to the community [chat](https://t.me/grammyjs).